# Jquery splitter

Tags: jquery-plugins

i am using a jquery page-splitter plugin in a java application, from here: http://methvin.com/splitter/

This plugin works if you provide input a div which has structure like

```
<div id=parent>
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

but i dont want this structure because i cant change my html structure. I have div located at same level and i want them as left,right element.

The reason why i cant append my html div into plugin understandable div because my html div have iframe and if i am trying to reposition the div then the iframe content is lost..please suggesr any solution..or how to make my my own splitter?

Comment: Div structure which plugin understand is a parent div containing two child div which will be splitted horizontally or vertically

Comment: Yes..You are correct.In the right div i have a iframe